# JavaScript array with decimal index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a code:

```
var arr = {"1":["val"],"1.5":["val"],"2":["val"],"2.5":["val"],"3":["val"]};

jQuery.each( arr, function( index, value ) {
    console.log(index + ':' + value)
});
```

I need to display the each element that how is in array, but I get:

```
1:val
2:val
3:val
1.5:val
2.5:val
```

But I need to get it in this form:

```
1:val
1.5:val
2:val
2.5:val
3:val
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't an array, it's a non-array object. Non-array objects have no intrinsic order.*  To impose order on them, you get the keys (property names), put *them* in order, then loop over those names. Something like this:

```
var arr = {"1":["val"],"1.5":["val"],"2":["val"],"2.5":["val"],"3":["val"]};

jQuery.each( Object.keys(arr).sort(sortNumerically), function( index, name ) {
    console.log(name + ':' + arr[name])
});

// Somewhere reusable
function sortNumerically(a, b) {
    var anum = parseFloat(a),
        bnum = parseFloat(b);
    return anum - bnum;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/liqav/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/liqav/1/edit)

`Object.keys` is an ES5 function that gives you an array of the names of the "own" enumerable properties of an object, as an array. (You can add a shim for it on pre-ES5 engines.) `Array#sort` sorts arrays in place. (The default sort is lexigraphic, so I've put in a function to do a numeric comparison.)  Then we loop through the sorted array, examining the object's properties.

---

(* For that matter, JavaScript's standard arrays only have order by convention, e.g., the numeric relationship of the array indexes. Except for when engines do optimizations on them, they're [not really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), nor are the entries necessarily stored in numeric order.)